# Attach a pre-exising SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a `SQLite` database that I already created and it has data in it.

Now I just want to attach the database with existing tables and keys without any changes to the Android application and use it.

Most of the samples about `SQLite` databases in Android involve creating the database in the application, [like this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android).  But my database file already exists.

After some searching, I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133760/attach-sqlite-database-in-android-with-sqliteopenhelper) about database attachment but it isn't clear and I don't understand where I should put the database file and how to call the attachment query for it.

Comment: Use `SQLiteAssetHelper`: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [sqllite asset helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper)

It's the best lib out there that serves your purpouse. I also wrote a blogpost about preloading sqllite data (and other stuff) [here](http://mytechaddiction.blogspot.it/2014/04/preloading-localized-data-in-sqllte.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = "/path/to/database/file";
SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, 0);
```